# Why onReceive() of Broadcastreceiver is not getting called when calendar time set to greater than current time?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, repeat

Hi I am working on setting daily alarm in android application where I want to set alarm daily at 6 pm. I followed the tutorial given on http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html.

Below is the code I am using:-

```
 public class SampleAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    // The app's AlarmManager, which provides access to the system alarm services.
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    // The pending intent that is triggered when the alarm fires.
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
        Intent service = new Intent(context, SampleSchedulingService.class);

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Set the alarm's trigger time to 8:30 a.m.
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);
        Log.i("Hour",""+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        Log.i("Min",""+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        // Set the alarm to fire at approximately 8:30 a.m., according to the device's
        // clock, and to repeat once a day.
        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

        // Enable {@code SampleBootReceiver} to automatically restart the alarm when the
        // device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);           
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        // If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
        if (alarmMgr!= null) {
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }

        // Disable {@code SampleBootReceiver} so that it doesn't automatically restart the 
        // alarm when the device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

In  above code when I set Hour_Of_Day to 18 (As I want to set alarm at 6pm) broadcast receiver never gets received. But when I set the Hour_Of_Day less than current one (For example if current Hour_Of_Day is 14 then value is less than 14) then BroadcastReceiver gets perfectly called.
I am not getting what's exactly happening here. Will anyone please tell me how to resolve this? 
I have declared everything like given tutorial.
Please help me!!

Comment: It's natural, Alarm Manager will not trigger the Alarm of the same time on which it's initiating but will trigger for the next day.

Comment: @ jitain sharma : So it will work on next day's 6pm perfectly?

Comment: @jitain sharma :Also is there any way to debug? I mean what should I do if I want to debug?

Comment: @user3458918 : What time-zone are you in? Using `RTC_WAKEUP` means you need to set the time as UTC.

Comment: @Squonk : How can I set time as UTC? will you please guide me?

Comment: @user3458918 : Try removing this line `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Comment: see [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: @user3458918 : Did removing that line fix the problem?

Comment: @Squonk : Not exactly but it got set properly. I am testing now . . hoping that it will work. . thanks.